# How to fill this gap in the drywall on an odd corner?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

The whole house has these cheap strips all over it. We're starting to take them down. This one on the corner has a big gap in it. Do we just put joint compound in there? Or is there something else we're supposed to put there?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that an outside corner in the picture?

Comment: There are larger versions of corner bead that JACK (the other Jack) answered with too. Just a mention, it looks like the lower half of the wall in the upper picture is past the plane of the other wall. If it is, before any corner bead is put on, the drywall that is projecting past another wall needs to be cut back so it does not force the corner bead into an odd position.

Comment: Another question, are these supposed to be 90 degree corners or 45 degree corners?

Comment: Yes it's an outside corner.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you! It looks a lot worse than it is because I hadn't taken that other strip off just yet, but it does still stick out. They're more like 135 degree angles.

Comment: thats Not really bad I have found much worse over the years with only paper tape but metal pre taped is what I would use , good scissors to cut the metal or tin snips (yes I have used sewing scissors in a pinch).

Answer (score 2):

There are pre-taped corners that are available from you home store that would look great here. You have to mud the corner part of the wall and then install the corner and then mud the tape on each side and then finish with a skimcoat. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to bend them to fit a 135° angle or do they sell different ones for different shapes angles?

Comment: Like Jack said, (the other Jack) you can get larger corners than the one I showed. You can bend them but it has to be an even bend. Place the corner pointed edge up and use a furring strip or other straight piece of wood to evenly bend the corner down.

Comment: I fully agree get the big ones and flex them prior to install the metal ones will hold when bent, then a coat of mud and slap em in place work them down let dry then fill to the metal bead with a wide knife , +

Comment: The bigger ones are actually paper coated vinyl, one of the brand names are Flextape I think. They cover about 4" on either side of a splayed corner. I just did a fast search using that term, it did not show what I described, but it is out there

Comment: Certainteed makes a type of it called Easy Flex tape pro. It is made so it takes just a skim coat over the edges.